# In this React based form, I am confused by what's going on with `setValues`. Can you help elaborate?

Tags: reactjs, forms, use-state

First of all, we have a small react based form with three fields (first name, last name, email) followed with a "register" button. Now, the author is using the following code to organise the state.

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    email: '',
});
```

And then the author uses the following code to capture typed in values from the field `onChange`. However, I am not able to fully comprehend what is going on. I would love for someone to help me explain this.

```
const handleFirstNameInputChange = (event) => {
    event.persist();
    setValues((values) => ({
        ...values,
        firstName: event.target.value,
    }));
};
```

I am especially perplexed by what's going on with `setValues` here. For instance, why are we trying to "spread" the values in this scenario? Why is the `firstName` followed after the spread? Why is the anonymous function body wrapped with parentheses and braces?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React can set state synchronously or asynchronously. This means that your state doesn't necessarily change immediately when you call `setValues()`. Instead, your state may update a few milliseconds later. It is up to the inner-workings of React to decide when to update your state.

As a result, React allows us to use callbacks when setting the state. The callback will give you access to the previous state which you can then use in your updated state by returning from the callback. With that in mind in your `setValues()` method:

```
setValues((values) => ({
  ...values,
  firstName: event.target.value,
}));
```

Above `values` is your previous state - so an object. When you spread an object into another object, you're grabbing all the enumerable (own) keys from the `values` object and adding them to the new object you're spreading into. You can think of this as merging the properties from one object into a new object:

```js
const a = {
  aKey: 1,
  bKey: 1.5
}

const b = {
  ...a,
  bKey: 2
}

/*
b is interpreted as:
{
  akey: 1,
  bKey: 1.5,
  bKey: 2 <-- Objects can't have duplicate keys, so this one overwrites the above
}

... which then evaluates to:
{
  "aKey": 1,
  "bKey": 2
}

*/

console.log(b);
```

Your callback then returns the newly updated object (as this is an arrow function it is an implicit return). Note that the object is wrapped in parenthesis `( )`. This is because without the parenthesis the `{ }` for the object literal would be interpreted as a code-block (so the code would be interpreted as a function-body) and not an object literal.

```
// Arrow function with a body (ie: code-block)
// code-block --- \/
const foo = () => {

};

// Arrow function with implict return
const bar = () => ({ // <--- object

});
```

---

A note on `event.persist()`.

React uses [SyntheticEvents](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html). A SyntheticEvent is a wrapper to the native event object which gets passed to your event handler. React uses this wrapper for cross-browser compatibility. However, SyntheticEvents are a little different to native events as they're ["pooled"](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling). Pooling essentially means that the SyntheticEvents are reused, meaning that the same object reference of `event` can be used for other events throughout your application. Because of this, the object needs to be "nullified" after it's done being used. "nullifying" the object means to make the values of the keys of the object `null` once the event-handler is finished. So the keys of the event object remain, however, the values of the keys are set to `null`. This way, when another event triggers, React can grab the SythenticEvent and populate its values. React uses this concept of pooling as creating a new SyntheticEvent instance for each event can be costly, thus, using a reference is more efficient as a new instance doesn't need to be created for each event.

The reason why react nullifies the event is because of performance reasons. When the values are set to null, the old values can be garbage collected which will free-up the application's memory.

So, the properties of `event` will be nullified once the event-handler has finished executing. As noted, `setValues()` may be asynchronous, meaning that it may run *after* your event handler has finished executing and nullifying the event object. As a result, performing `event.target.value` would result in an error due to the nullification of the `event`. So, to stop this error from occurring, we can stop the event from being pooled and thus nullified by using `event.persist()`. Now the `event` won't be reused and so there is no need for it to be nullified. As a result, another synthetic event will be added to the pool to replace the old one. For your case, persisting the entire event object is a little over-kill since all you want to persist is the `event.target.value`. This can be done by saving the *value* of `event.target.value` in a variable.

```
const firstName = event.target.value;
```

When the object is nullified, this won't impact our `firstName` variable as it is storing a value and not a reference to the value within the object. This way, when you set the state, your callback can close over this variable as use it just fine:

```
const firstName = event.target.value;
setValues((values) => ({
  ...values,
  firstName
}));
```

Event pooling isn't something that you'll need to worry about for too much longer as it will no longer be used in React 17 (as it seems that it doesn't improve performance in modern browsers).

Answer (score 1):

`setValues` is the setter from your React state. It sets your email, first name, and password.

It should be more like this.

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
    event.persist();
    
    // the name here would be the key of your state object.
    // i.e email, password and firstname
   // it should be defined as the name in your input field.
    const name = event.target.name;
    const value = event.target.value;
    
    setValues((values) => ({
        ...values,
        [name]: value,
    }));
};
```

You could use your fields like

```
// the name "email" has to be passed through here.
// you could access both the value and the key in your `handleChange` handler
<input type="email" name="email" onChange={handleChange} value={values.email} />
```

You could check the working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zynnkw?file=src%2FApp.js)

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion @PrateekThapa. However, before I go there... I would really like to understand the snippet posted... Especially, `setValues((values) => ({
        ...values,
        firstName: event.target.value,
    }));`. What is the role of trying to "spread" the values here? Secondly, why is the body of the anonymous function  wrapped in parantheses as well as braces? What's going on?

Comment: `setValues((values) => ({ ...values,  [name]: value,     }));` What this says is let's merge the previous state with new. As far the parenthesis is concerned, it is implicit return. It is basically returning the object. You could check the [rules](https://medium.com/@bunlong/arrow-functions-return-rules-in-javascript-b63ed5f25994) here.

Comment: "Implicit return"... Aaah, of course!! So the anonymous function is passed as an argument only so that it returns a new object to the `setValues`. This is key to my understanding. Thanks. However, is it correct to say that `...values` is returning all the existing name and value pairs... Including `firstName`? If so, won't the explicit addition of `firstName` and its value at the end cause a duplicate within the returning object?

Comment: There are no duplicates in an object with the same key. The explicit addition of firstname gets merged replacing the old ones.

Comment: Aaah, okay! So, even if I was to "add" `firstName` 5 times with various values, the last one gets to replace all the other ones. Correct?

Comment: Yup. Do check the example. It is better for you to see it yourself, right

Comment: Also, could you explain why you used `[name]` instead of just `name` in your suggestion?

Comment: it's dynamic property names. Read [this](https://usefulangle.com/post/196/javascript-object-dynamic-key#:~:text=ES6%20has%20brought%20%22Computed%20property,put%20between%20square%20brackets%20%5B%20%5D.)

Comment: Oh wow, that is amazing. Although, the variable contents are normally used... In this case, for the object literal, it's important to use the square brackets. Prateek.... You are a star! Thank you so much.